# AspectJ: Override a method and call the overridden method through `super`

Tags: java, aspectj, super

I'd like to ask if it's possible with AspectJ to override a method from a superclass, and in the method body to call a superclass's method through the `super` keyword. For example, consider the following oversimplified scenario:

Superclass:

```
package test;

public class Parent {

  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Parent is doing something");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent instance = new Child();
    instance.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Subclass:

```
package test;

public class Child extends Parent {
}
```

Aspect:

```
package test;

public aspect MyAspect {

  public void Child.doSomething() {
    super.doSomething();
    System.out.println("Child is doing something");
  }
}
```

In short, in class `Child` I'm creating a method which overrides a method from class `Parent`, and I want the new method to call the overridden method in the superclass.

When I run this, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: test.Child.ajc$superDispatch$test_Child$doSomething()V
    at test.MyAspect.ajc$interMethod$test_MyAspect$test_Child$doSomething(MyAspect.aj:6)
    at test.Child.doSomething(Child.java:1)
    at test.Parent.main(Parent.java:11)
```

I understand that I *can* achieve this through a bytecode instrumentation library, but the project, on which I'm working now, uses AspectJ and I must do this through AspectJ.

Comment: This code works flawlessly in AspectJ 1.8.13. Which version do you use?

Comment: I use Spring Tool Suite 3.9.2, a.k.a. STS, based on Eclipse 4.7.2. I have created an AspectJ project and all the sources above are in that project. The project claims that its AspectJ Runtime Library is `org.aspectj.runtime_1.8.13.201710301818.jar`. I run this inside STS (Ctrl+F11). But when I run this on the command line, through `java -classpath .;C:\Java\ide\sts\3.9.2.RELEASE\plugins\org.aspectj.runtime_1.8.13.201710301818.jar test/Parent`, I get the same exception.

Comment: Okay, I also downloaded `aspectjrt` and ran `java -classpath .;aspectjrt-1.8.13.jar test/Parent`. And I got the same exception.

How do you run this in order to make it work?

Comment: Copy & paste into Eclipse AspectJ project and run. I can also compile and run with AspectJ compiler directly from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is kind of difficult to post code or command line in-/output in a comment, I am writing this as an answer. Imagine you have the source files in subfolder `src` and want the compiled output ending up in `bin` (standard Eclipse directory layout), you can do this:

```
xx> java -version

java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

xx> ajc -sourceroots src -d bin -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\AspectJ\lib\aspectjrt.jar"

xx> java -cp bin;"C:\Program Files\Java\AspectJ\lib\aspectjrt.jar" test.Parent

Parent is doing something
Child is doing something
```

It also compiles in my standard Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) with manually installed AJDT. Don't know about STS, I never use it.

Comment: Yep, inspired by your input, I just installed Eclipse Oxygen + AJDT and this whole thing actually works there. (It also works when using `ajc` manually.) So, I guess either STS is messed up in general, or _my_ particular STS is messed up.

It's actually worth pointing out that I have actual advices, some of them not trivial, and they work fine in that same STS. But _this particular_ thing (with `super`) doesn't work. Weird, this.

Thank you for taking the time to respond.